# Many to many where_in syntax for Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm struggling to make a join query using Laravel's Eloquent ORM

I have two classes which have a many to many relationship

```
class Type extends Eloquent
{
    public function activities()
    {
        return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Activity');
    }
}
class Activity extends Eloquent
{
    public function types()
    {
        return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Type');
    }
}
```

In my database I have types, activities, and activities_types tables

I'm trying to recreate the following SQL query

```
SELECT a . * 
FROM activities a
JOIN activities_types at ON a.id = at.activities_id
WHERE at.type_id
IN ( 1, 2, 4 ) 
GROUP BY a.id
```

I just haven't grasped the ORM syntax. I've tried

$activities = Activity::types().where_in("id", $types)->get();

but I get an error `"Non-static method Activity::types() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context"`

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationships are not defined as static method. Therefore you can't use them like `::type()`. Additionally, relationships doesn't give you what you want exactly. Because you are interested in with just activities column, you can do like this:

```
$activities = Type::where_in("id", $types)->get()->activites()->group_by('id')->get();
```

On the other hand, I think you can handle this by using join:

```
$activites = Activity::select('activities.*')->join('activities_types','activities.id','=','activities_types.activities_id')->where_in('activities_types.type_id',$types)->group_by('activities.id')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you - I'm still fumbling my way through this, but this is a great help